# How to Programmatically Turn on Do Not Disturb in iOS7

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios7

I cannot find a good tutorial to turn on Do Not Disturb for iOS7. I found some stuff that dealt with iOS6 and iOS5, but they included deprecated and outdated material. In short, how could I programmatically turn on Do Not Disturb? I have seen apps like Call Bliss and am wondering how that works.

Comment: This isn't possible using the public APi's available even on iOS7

Comment: @ShamsAhmed Then how do apps that disable messaging and calling while driving work?

Comment: @John can you name the app that is doing this?

Answer (score 0):

To be clear to any other visitors to this page.

There is no public API that manages the "Do Not Disturb" feature. There are also no frameworks that can achieve this.

Comment: Then how do apps that disable messaging and calling while driving work?